# How Do You Get The Store Secure URL in Magento?

Tags: forms, magento

I have a form in Magento that is displayed over the insecure URL (http) but I need it to submit to the secure URL (https).

I display the URL I currently use the following code:

```
Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)
```

I am assuming I need to change the URL_TYPE_WEB to something else. Does anyone know what that something else is?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
Mage::getUrl('',array('_secure'=>true))
```

I think that gets you the base secure url, I believe.

```
Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login',array('_secure'=>true))
```

Will get you to the login page.  In other words,

```
Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action',array('_secure'=>true))
```

Will get you to any page you want, just substitute 'module/controller/action' for the appropriate combo.

Edit -- Fixed Typos

Comment: As well as `_secure` there is also `_forced_secure`. A full reference can be found [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters)

Comment: If you are loading a script rather than a site url, you'll get a trailing slash with this function, so be sure to `rtrim` out that slash.

Answer (score 11):

http://blog.geekslikeshinythings.com/2014/12/magento-force-secure-urls-https-on-all.html

this works in Mageno 1.9.1
use your app/etc/config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <frontend>
    <secure_url>
      <all>/</all>
    </secure_url>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

If user is using https, this should force all urls to rewrite (created as) to https.

Comment: This seems to work for me for Mage::getUrl(), but NOT for Mage::getBaseUrl() - Strange, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks! That one fixed my issue.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
    Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_SECURE_BASE_URL);
```

to read the the configuration value inside magento that has been set inside admin.

Answer (score 3):

this worked to me

```
echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/loginPost',array('_secure'=>true));
```

For example:

if you browsing with **http** then

```
echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/loginPost',array('_secure'=>true));
// http://dominio.com/customer/account/loginPost
```

if you browsing with **https** then

```
echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/loginPost',array('_secure'=>true));
// https://dominio.com/customer/account/loginPost
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in code and also from xml.

For example, if you want to set https for the check out page then you have to add the below code in your custom config.xml:

```
<code>
        <secure_url>
                <checkout_onepage>/checkout/onepage</checkout_onepage>
                <checkout_multishipping>/checkout/multishipping</checkout_multishipping>
        </secure_url>
</code>
```

Magento has a default feature for https for check out so you can do the same thing for other pages like for the customer page:

```
<code>
        <secure_url>
                <customer>/customer/</customer>
        </secure_url>
</code>
```

I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Tried this its working for me.

Mage::getUrl('',array('_secure'=>true))

> After added this code finally its look like below

```
IWD.ProductVideoView.urlGetVideo = "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('iwd_productvideo/player/getvideo/',array('_secure'=>true)); ?>?isAjax=true";
```