# Magento Admin stuck at "Please wait" when updating order

Tags: magento, ssl, https, magento-1.9

I've switched my site to SSL. And set both Unsecure og Secure Base URL to https.
But when I try to update an order when adding or removing products in backend, the site gets stuck with a "Please wait" message.
In the console I can see that it's not loading due to Mixed Content:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/index.php/admin/sales_order_create/index/key/4e0ec3c2ddd4bd7919035ba6f18b23dc' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure form action 'http://example.com/index.php/admin/sales_order_create/showUpdateResult/key/d7d847bf0a9637587ce481f58c88e703'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

How do I fix this https issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https Mixed Content errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451124/https-mixed-content-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Try this code to your htaccess file.